# Constraining Laravel/Eloquent relationship based on parent column values?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models in Laravel and I need a specific relation between them.

The parent model `Track` has this relationship with `Wire`:

```
        public function wire()
        {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Wire', 'machineID', 'machineID');
        }
```

This relationship works however I need to constrain it.
Each row in `Track` has two values: `date_from` and `date_to`. 
Each `Wire` has a value `date`.

I need the relationship to be constrained to those `Wire` with a `date` between the `date_from` and `date_to` of the parent `Track`.

I'm sure there must be a way, but I've tried the following (below) and nothing has worked.

Thanks for all your help!

**Method 1**

```
        public function wire()
        {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Wire', 'machineID', 'machineID')
                  ->whereBetween("wire.date", ["track.dateFrom", "track.dateTo"];
        }
```

**Method 2**

```
        ->with(["wire" => function($query) {
            $query->whereBetween("wire.date", ["track.dateFrom", "track.dateTo"]);
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

using **WhereHas** can filter track refer wire so show only the track has wire between two dates  :

```
   Track::WhereHas("wire", function($query) {
            $query->whereBetween("wire.date", ["track.dateFrom", "track.dateTo"])->get();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sadly I can't seem to get this working either. I need both the "wire" and "track" models to be returned, but I think this would just filter the "track" model?

Comment: this query track has wire so you querying track and wire, see my edited answer